# How to create Autocomplete TextField in Swiftui?

Tags: ios, swiftui, autocomplete, textfield

when add text in TextField.We should get suggestion according to the text we have type irrespective of case sensitivity.when we click on that the suggestion should add on array.

Answer (score 1):

When we type something in textfield we will show suggestions.if we type on suggestion button we will append that suggestion into selectedSuitableFor State variable and empty textfield and also turn suggestion to false

declaring variable

```
@State var suggestions = ["Radiologist","Pathalogist","Surgeon","Orthopedic",
                          "Radiologist1","Pathalogist1","Surgeon1","Orthopedic1",
                          "Radiologist2","Pathalogist2","Surgeon2","Orthopedic2",
                          "Radiologist3","Pathalogist3","Surgeon3","Orthopedic3",
                          "Radiologist4","Radiologist5","Radiologist6","Radiologist7","Radiologist8",
                          "Radiologist9","Radiologist10"
]

@State var showSuggestions:Bool = false
@State var selectedSuitableFor:[String] = []
@State var selectedSuitableForItems:[[String]] = [[String]]()
```

```
                VStack {
                    TextField("Suitable For", text: $suitableFor)
                        .onChange(of: suitableFor) { newValue in
                            showSuggestions = true
                        }
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    
                    if showSuggestions && !suitableFor.isEmpty {
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVStack(alignment:.leading) {
                                ForEach(suggestions.filter({ $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(suitableFor) }), id: \.self) { suggestion in
                                    ZStack {
                                        Button(action: {
                                            if (!selectedSuitableFor.contains(suggestion)){
                                                selectedSuitableFor.append(suggestion)
                                            }
                                            
                                            suitableFor = ""
                                            showSuggestions = false
                                        }) {
                                            Text(suggestion)
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(maxHeight: 100)
                            .background(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
```